# cannot resolve symbol 'FirebaseFirestore'

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So after looking a lot for a solution of this problem, I found a answer in one project on a Github and decide post here. Just add this lines of your class project and going to dismiss the error **cannot resolve symbol 'FirebaseFirestore'**

```
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this, please add the following dependencies to your build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

The last dependenciy is now mandatory.

> Your app gradle file now has to explicitly list `com.google.firebase:firebase-core` as a dependency for Firebase services to work as expected.

Don't also forget to add in your top level build.gradle file, the following Google Service plugin:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this `dependencies` in your **build.gradle**

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.4'
```

then **syn** your project.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart